# Why do these decorator variables not get destroyed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, decorator, python-decorators

Suppose you have a decorator function that creates a dict to store already calculated results for performance reasons. E.g.:

```
def memoize(func):

    cache = dict()

    def memoized_func(*args, **kwargs):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]

        result = func(*args)
        cache[args] = result
        return result

    return memoized_func
```

When I decorate a function with `myfunc = memoize(myfunc)`, I have a hard time understanding why this works.

I have initially thought that cache would get lost after returning the memoized function, as it goes out of scope. I would only return a reference to the decorated function. Obviously, this is not the case.

Can somebody tell me what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: That's what a *closure* is.

Comment: The returned function as a reference to the variable, hence it is not garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator function have self nonlocal scope where storing cache. This scope doesn't destroy after function call. More info there https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement